# Difference between the number of emails sent in Journey Builder and Email Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud

I sent 14 000 emails in the journey, the email in the Journey Builder doesn't have any hard/soft errors.

[image]

When I look on the email studio, the number of total sent is almost 400 lower than the number of the total sent emails in the journey.

[image]

How it is possible if there were not errors in the email activity in the journey.

Comment: Please add more context on this as I am unsure how Automation Studio and Journey Builder Email Activity are related in this question? Did you do two duplicate sends in each tool? Did you pull analytics from JB and then run a query in AS and they came back with different results? etc.. and when you clarify, please provide generalized examples for us to better compare 'apples to apples'.

Comment: I wouldn’t trust the numbers shown in JB, I’d trust the numbers shown in Email Studio

Comment: I'd recommend looking to the data views table for a more accurate view of opens. The fact that it's such a nice round number (400), makes me think that the last batch of sends were not yet captured when the report was created.

Comment: Is it any way to check what happened with the emails which are not included in bounces and dissapeared in the journey builder?

Comment: @JordanB - yup, this blog post covers a query you can use that would consolidate all that for you - https://sfmarketing.cloud/2021/11/18/consolidate-tracking-data-for-journey-builder-email-sends/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see in Journey Builder there is in relation to the contacts processed for that activity, not the actual send results. This number does not account for unsubscribes, exclusions, suppressions, List Detective filters, and so on.

Meaning that 14000 were accepted by the activity as valid contacts, but then inside the activity those 400 were not able to be added to the send queue (for one reason or another) and so it shows the total actually sent being 400 less.

What is shown in the tracking tab, via Data Views, tracking extracts or SOAP Objects is the place I would view as the most accurate numbers to work from.

As a note though, I believe the email Activity itself should have some activity tracking info that you can look at and explore as that might be closer to what you are seeing in tracking.

Comment: The journey is populated by the automation which exclude all users from all suppresion lists, exclusions etc. If the email is excluded by the list detective, the hard errors appear in the email activity details, but my email activity doesn't have any hard errors.

Comment: @JordanB If you compare your Email Analytics in the Journey, it should show you the notsent amount as well as the sent. List Detective is not triggered via the contacts processed part. It is not until the activity itself begins processing for entering send queue that it would bump it out for list detective. So in your view, it would show as processed, but it would then be in the 'not sent' in Email Analytics and Tracking tab, etc.